# Forming api request

Tags: javascript, api, request

Can someone explain me how can I form and api request using JavaScript fetch or axios to this endpoint ?

This is Russian website in docs there is said how to implement request with WSDL .NET SOAP and JSON. I was always using JavaScript. I have no idea about first three methods.

But even json request it’s confusing me. I’ve never done such thing. Here is the code from docs

```
$data = array(
    'search_code' => 'C110',
    'search_cross' => 'off',
    'user_id' => 1000000,
    'user_login' => 'login',
    'user_password' => 'pass',
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$request = array(
    'action' => 'SearchStart',
    'data' => $data_string,
);

$result = curl_start($request);
function curl_start($request) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://www.avtoto.ru/?soap_server=json_mode" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $request);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Can someone help me to form request as I would do it from JavaScript client ?

Comment: are you gettng any error? like bad request etc

Comment: I don’t know at all how to form a request. I used to do it with fetch or axios. And body objects. Here is docs I don’t understand how it works

Comment: Looks like in docs they use other language but JavaScript

Comment: do it the way you normally do, you would need api_key if its required 
share the api link, would be easier then